# Create a program(C#) that catch's the Html's links that I want and export the results an Excel document

Tags: c#, .net, html

Some day the professor tells to me that he want to do a website that needs much data, and he wants me to do the copy and the stick that we should bring the links's content to the Excel, but  it's too much.

So I need to to do a program (C#) that it could catch the Html's links what I want and export them to an Excel document.

If somebody knows a little about it, please tell me some ideas. Because It's my first time to do the work, and I don't have the ideas to do preparation.

Just tell me what I must learn. Just take several minutes for my work which takes too much. Thank you too much!

Comment: If you want people to do your homework, you should spend a little more effort in your question. It is hard to understand!

Comment: Please help us understand what you want. Do you want to copy links from HTML and paste them into an Excel sheet?

Comment: thank your advice,and I'll do my best to improve it .

Answer (score 3):

Although there are many ways to access the page itself: [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx), or [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx)/[HttpWebResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.aspx) if you need something more complex. I believe that using Regular expressions to parse the pages(once you get them) and retrieve the links is definetly the way to go.

Comment: I'm not sure regex is the best tool for this job, far better to properly parse the HTML into a DOM using something like HTML Agility Pack.

Comment: @MattDavey - would that be faster than regular expressions if you just need to pull out some information from a webpage?

Comment: @BojanSkrchevski I guess it comes down to personal preference :) The difference in speed is not a concern since the time taken to scrape the data would be insignificant compared to the time taken to pull it down the network.

Answer (score 2):

The term you should look for is *[web scraping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping)*. Very easy to do using simple C# code like [this](http://www.dotnetperls.com/scraping-html). Also writing the excel file ([example](http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-create-excel.htm)) is something very easy to find searching for it on Google.